# PHP threat : Processing code which does not exist

Tags: php, ajax

I am developing my websites signup page , it uses AJAX and PHP to validate the form. Now i am amazed with this paranormal thing.

**->  I changed my code of  AJAX-PHP call which tells user about their *verification number  validity*** , if verification number is earlier taken or **less than 3 characters it shows me error BY ECHO STATEMENT "3 - 16 characters please" .**

**->now i changed my code to ECHO error if username is NOT EQUAL TO length 5** and ECHO statements **to print "CHECK USERNAME AGAIN "**, BUT even after saving my new code with new ECHO statements my SIGNUP page is showing me the same last ECHO statements which was saved in last code.

**HERE IS WHAT I TRIED :**

1)restart all services of localhost (WAMP)
2)restart all browers 
3) clear history , cookies and everything else in it.

Have a look at my 1st code :

```
<?php
// Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
include_once("dbconfig.php");

$username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_config, $sql); 
$uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">3 - 16 characters please</strong>';
    echo "<br/>";
    exit();

}
 if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;"> must begin with a letter</strong>';

}
 if ($uname_check < 1) {
     echo "<br/>";
    echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK .       </strong>';

} else {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';

}
exit();
 }
?>
```

**Now this is what i UPDATED**

```
<?php
// Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
include_once("dbconfig.php");

$username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_config, $sql); 
$uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if (strlen($username) != 5 ) {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">Check again</strong>';
    echo "<br/>";
    exit();

}
 if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;"> must begin with a letter</strong>';

}
 if ($uname_check < 1) {
     echo "<br/>";
    echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK .       </strong>';

} else {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';

}
exit();
 }
?>
```

**OUTPUT after trying all things**

"3-16 characters please"

Comment: Looks like the AJAX call is reaching a different php file. You may have a duplicated file with the 1st php code, go over the file names, and check your javascript code for the correct php target file.

Comment: `var_dump($username)`, too, and make sure your regex is working properly.

Comment: There is no any other file with same name or same code , just have backup in NON WAMP folder. that to not active in browser